# Active Directory search filter example

Tags: search, active-directory, ldap, openldap

I can't find the meaning, the difference between these two examples for search filter

```
(&(objectClass=user)(sn=*)(bysUserName=*)(|(bysUserName={0})(cn={0})))

(&(|(bysUserName={0})(cn={0}))(objectClass=User))
```

Can anyone help me figure out these two filters? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you reorder them a bit, I guess you'll see the difference:

```
(&(objectClass=user)(sn=*)(bysUserName=*)(|(bysUserName={0})(cn={0})))

(&(objectClass=User)                     (|(bysUserName={0})(cn={0})))
```

The first one has **additional** restrictions on `sn` (must contain *some value*) and `bysUserName` (same thing - must contain *some value*) that aren't present in the second filter.

Basically, the `&` defines an **AND** condition, while the `|` is an **OR** operator - so the first filter requires your LDAP objects to satisfy:

- (1) `objectClass` must be `user`
- **AND** (2) `sn` must contain *something* (cannot be empty)
- **AND** (3) `bysUserName` must contain *something*
- **AND** (4) either `bysUserName` or `cn` must match the value that replaces the `{0}` placeholder

The second filter just requires points (1) and (4)

Comment: Thx @marc_s for your help .
Sorry but I can't get what you mean about point (4). could you please help me understand this point (4) in more detail.

Comment: @Feres_F: well, there seems to be a string replacement happening here, and `{0}` will be replaced with a value - and the filter requires that **either** the `bysUserName` **or** the `cn` matches that value

Comment: If we suppose that the returned serach like this one:
There is 5 LDAP entries which hava an sn and byUserName != Null (contain some value like you said before) and they are user entities.

Here what is the meaning of cn={0} ??

Comment: @Feres_F: as I tried to explain - the filter requires that ***EITHER*** the `bysUserName` ***OR*** the `cn` is set. If you already have a value in `bysUserName` - then perfect! This condition will always be true, and whatever value you might have in `cn` is not considered...